# GroupSizeDefinition is not working with style defined for ribbon group

Tags: wpf, templates, ribbon-control

I have a main list which is a ribbon group. 
Inside each ribbon group there is another list called subfuctions for ribbon buttons.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTempl">
                <RibbonButton IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Label="{Binding Path=SubFunctionName}" Command="{Binding SubFunctionCommand}" LargeImageSource="{Binding LargeButtonImage}" SmallImageSource="{Binding SmallButtonImage}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection x:Key="groupSize">
                <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition IsCollapsed="False" />
            </RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection>
            <Style TargetType="RibbonGroup" x:Key="groupStyle">
                <Setter Property="GroupSizeDefinitions" Value="{StaticResource groupSize}"/>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubFunctions}"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource buttonTempl}"/>
                <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" Value="{Binding RibbonGroupSmallImageSource}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="RibbonTab" x:Key="tabStyle">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="Pump"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MainFunctions}"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource groupStyle}"/>
            </Style>
```

Hence groupSizedefinition is working if I use ribbongroup as separate as below:
`<RibbonGroup Header="Selection" Name="SelectionMenu" GroupSizeDefinitions="{StaticResource groupSize}">`

but not working with the above code that is with template.

What could be done to work groupsizedefinition with ribbongroup defined as style?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but it is too much for a comment.

I tried to reproduce this problem and observed the following effects using the "Live Visual Tree" and the "Live Property Explorer" windows in the debugger.

**Specifying the GroupSizeDefinitions explicitly**

```
<RibbonGroup Style="{StaticResource groupStyle}" GroupSizeDefinitions="{StaticResource groupSize}" />
```

the GroupSizeDefinitions in the style is crossed out, and the local definition is used

[image]

**Specifying the GroupSizeDefinitions in the styls**

```
<RibbonGroup Style="{StaticResource groupStyle}"/>
```

The Live property explorer shows a Local definition, which in my opinion is not present, is also crossed out.

The GroupSizeDefinitions which are actually being used are under the heading **Coercion**.

[image]

I'm afraid that I can't explain that, but maybe somebody else can.